# Python 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split' while converting HH:MM:SS.MS TO MS

Tags: time, split, numpy-ndarray

I have a string array of time which is in the format of hh:mm:ss.ms. I am writing a function to convert to milliseconds format. While the function work for individual entry but fails to output for the entire array.

Here is my code

```
 Time1=  np.array(['18:01:52.388','18:01:52.431','18:01:52.848']) 

 def get_msec(time_str):
     """Get milliseconds from time."""

    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int((int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s))*1000)

 print(get_msec(Time1))
```

Could someone please pinpoint me where I am doing mistake.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with below code and its now working

```
 Time1=  np.array(['18:01:52.388','18:01:52.431','18:01:52.848'])

 def get_msec(time_str):
  """Get Seconds from time."""
   new=[]
   for items in time_str:
   
   h, m, s = items.split(':')
   new.append(int((int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s))*1000))
 return new


 print(get_msec(Time1))
```

Thank you